# Efficiently append an element to each of the lists in a large numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, memory

I have a really large numpy of array of lists, and I want to append an element to each of the arrays. I want to avoid using a loop for the sake of performance.

The following syntax is not working.

```
a=np.array([[],[1],[0,1]])

[j.append(3) for j in a]
```

The expected result for this example would be

```
np.array([[3],[1,3],[0,1,3])
```

but I got

```
[None, None, None]
```

Any clue?

Comment: Really `np.array` on different-size lists won't get you much improvement if any over vanilla python.

Comment: `None` is an output of `append`. But if you check `a`, you'll see it has changed dynamically.

Comment: Why do you have python `list` objects inside of a `numpy.ndarray`? It really makes no sense. Note, don't use list-comprehensions for side-effects, `[j.append(3) for j in a]` is giving you `[None, None, None]` because `j.append(r)` will **always** return `None`, although note, the original lists inside `a` *should* be modified. but don't do things this way, use a regular loop. Better yet, don't use a numpy.ndarray of lists.

Comment: Iteration on an object dtype array is a bit slower than iteration on a list.  But both are faster than iterating on the rows of a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

`list.append()` returns `None`, so you're just seeing that the 3 append operations each returned `None`.

However, if you print the contents of `a` you'll find that the appends were successful.

```
a=np.array([[],[1],[0,1]])
[j.append(3) for j in a]
print(a)
# prints "[list([3]) list([1, 3]) list([0, 1, 3])]"
```

I wouldn't recommend using a numpy array of lists for anything, but maybe you have some special use case where this makes sense. I suggest asking a separate quesiton that looks at the reasoning for using a numpy array of lists

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why you  "wouldn't recommend using a numpy array of lists for anything," ?

Comment: @zell because it makes no sense. Why *would* you use a numpy.ndarray of lists? What advantage would it have?

Comment: @zell yeah there's really no upside to having an array of lists.

Comment: @Michael @ juanpa.arrivillaga Good points. Actually I got memory issue with large array lists. What would be a good alternative if I am to represent a large array where each item is of an unknown number of integers?

Comment: @zell It may be better for you to ask a new question, it's difficult to give an answer without the proper context