# Efficient data structure for storing N lists where N is very large

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I will need to store N lists, where N is large (1 million). For example,

```
[2,3]
[4,5,6]
...
[4,5,6,7]
```

Each item is a list of  about 0-10000 elements. I wanted to use a numpy array of lists, like

```
np.array([[2,3],[4,5,6])
```

Then I got efficiency issues when trying to append to the lists in the numpy array.  Also I was told here: [Efficiently append an element to each of the lists in a large numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436665/efficiently-append-an-element-to-each-of-the-lists-in-a-large-numpy-array), to not use numpy array of lists.

What would be a good data structure for storing such data, in terms of memory and time efficiency?

Comment: "...when trying to append to the lists in the numpy array" Does that mean while adding one more list to the numpy array, or while adding one more element to a specific list in the numpy array?

Comment: How large is N?

Comment: Please specify the order of ```n``` and what is your intended purpose for the nested lists

Comment: When discussing the efficiency of a data structure, one needs to explain how the data structure is going to be used, i.e. the operations that it is intended to support (e.g. addition, deletion, search, ...).

Comment: @IoaTzimas Good point. See my edits.

Comment: There isn't much difference.  Each list is stored in memory 'by itself'.  So a list of those list just contains those `N` references.  Same for an object dtype array.  And a `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the elements youre storing follow some pattern you must use nested list since there is no other way to get those elements out of the others.

In Python:

```
listOfLists = [[1,2,3],
               [4,5,6],
               [7,8,9]]
```

So whenever you want to operate with this list you can use numpy functions

```
>>> np.mean(listOfLists)
5.0
>>> np.max(listOfLists)
9
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use a dictionary:

```
d={}
for i in range(N):
  d[i]=your_nth_list
```

And you will simply append them by:

```
d[k].append(additional_items)
```

(It's efficient for 10.000.000 lists of 1000 items each)

Comment: I see that the answer is accepted, but I don't see how it addresses the mentioned problem -- which is to efficiently append elements to each of those lists. The dictionary will only help in efficiently grabbing a reference to a list, but not in efficiently appending an element to it.

Comment: What do you mean? Appending items to a list-dictionary value is pretty efficient, and it's also easy and tide. What's the problem exactly and what is the alternative that you would suggest?

Comment: A simple list of lists would actually be a bit more efficient and simpler.

Comment: @IoaTzimas -- Actually, I am no longer sure what the original problem of the OP is (All that was mentioned was that in the case of numpy-based solution, there were efficiency issues in appending elements to the lists). So, it may well be that the real (not mentioned) problem might have been in speed of accessing one list out of those `N` lists. Even if that were the real problem, I fail to see how dictionary-indexing is going to be faster than a (outer) list-indexing, when the indexes are merely integers. Perhaps experiment can decide best.

Comment: Right points above. Dictionaries finally gave me a memory issue. 1 million entries, with about 10 000 ints for each entry.

Answer (score 1):

try nested list

```
nestedList = [[2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested lists but they are not efficent in terms of complexity. In fact, it is linear, you could use dictionaries to get better results :

```
dict={}
for i in range(numer_of_lists) :
  dict[str(i)]=your_i-th_list
```

Then access the i-th element with`dict[str(i)] Then, appening an element will be as easy`

`

Comment: It's exactly what i suggested